# Закрыть программу, с выводом ошибки на с++

Tags: visual-c++

Пытаюсь собрать dll для игры. Как с dll при определенном условии, сначала закрыть игру. Потом вывести окно с ошибкой.

Comment: Из вашего вопроса вообще ничего не понятно. При чем сборка dll и закрытие какой-то программы?

Comment: Мне нужно с помощью dll закрыть программу к которой она подключена и вывести ошибку. Что тут не понятного?

Comment: ExitProcess() попробуйте

Comment: Это неверный подход. Библиотека может использоваться в приложениях разных типов, поэтому не должна закрывать то, о чём ей неизвестно заранее. Из функции dll возвращайте ошибку и уже уровнем выше принимайте решение, куда вывести окно и как закрыть приложение.

Comment: ExitProcess() закрывает и окно ошибки и саму игру, а нужно так что бы ошибка осталась а игра закрылась или же что бы игры закрылась через секунду после вывода сообщения

Comment: @ВладСергиенко Ну так поставьте паузу между выводом сообщения и ExitProcess.